Unable to :set printoptions for :hardcopy command
Just started using :hardcopy > x.ps to generate input to ps2pdf.
Result is satisfactory but I would like to change the printoptions to non-default values for header, margins and page size, e.g.
set printoptions "left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5"

which command is accepted without comment by Vim, but produces no change to printoptions
for it is still at its default setting
printoptions=paper:A4

help for printoptions says it is "{only available when compiled with +printer feature}" which I assume is true, or it would not have any printoptions setting at all.
What am I missing?

Don't assume, just run :echo has('printer'). If it says 1, the +printer feature is enabled, 0 otherwise. Or take a look in :version. (just realized Vivian has this covered in his answer, ah well...).

Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I accepted your answer and upvoted it at my previous visit. Would have thanked you then but was specifically discouraged from doing so, so I'll do that now, and also have ticked it

Thanks for the feedback :-)

I would do:
set printoptions=left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5

The set command needs:

an equal sign (=) and
no space ( ) in the argument.

Or the variable alternatives:
let &printoptions = "left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5"

For complex values that includes special characters (like  , |, \) this second form maybe more readable.
Remark: To verify that your version of Vim has the +printer feature you can use the :version command.

The other answers do a great job of explaining how to accomplish your goal. I'll play the unpopular part and explain your error.
Let's split your line into two parts and take a look at them individually:
set printoptions "left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5"
|<-- part 1 -->| |<----                 part 2                      ---->|

Part 1 is a complete Ex command: :set printoptions. Quoting from :help :set:
:se[t] {option}     Toggle option: set, switch it on.
                    Number option: show value.
                    String option: show value.

As 'printoptions' is a string option, this will show its current value in the command line. Nothing more.
Part 2 is a comment, because comments in Vimscript start with a quote. They can follow :set commands.
In fact, :help :comment features an example just like yours:
:set ai     "set 'autoindent' option

The solution - as already pointed out by Vivian and MDeBusk - is to use an equal sign and not to quote your string, see :help :set=:
set printoptions=left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5


Not unpopular with everyone.

Don't tell me you like to point out people's mistakes? I'd never have suspected.

Perhaps  I owe you an apology, my failure to press the tick symbol led you to believe I hadn't understood the answers provided and to provide your detailed explanation of my error.  Just the presence of the = sign in the solutions was sufficient.  My bad.

@user985675 "Perhaps I owe you an apology" - err... no. I wrote my answer because I felt there should be a more thorough explanation of the error. "Teach a man to fish" and all that. This is just how this site works and there's no need to apologize.

Try this and see what happens:
set printoptions=left:2pc,right:2pc,top:2pc,bottom:2pc,header:0,paper:A5

I just tried it and it worked here. Vim 9.1, patches through 408, compiled by me
